# JS узнать, установлено ли расширение Chrome

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, google-chrome

Мне нужно узнать, установлено ли у пользователя расширение.
Я пытался использовать:

```js
function detectExt(extId, callback){
    let oldEl = document.querySelector('#ext_check');
    if(oldEl) document.body.removeChild(oldEl);
    let s = document.createElement('script');
    s.id = 'ext_check';
    s.src = `chrome-extension://${extId}/manifest.json`;
    s.onload = ()=>{callback(true)};
    s.onerror = ()=>{callback(false)};
    document.body.appendChild(s);
}
```

```js
function detectExt(extId, iconFile, callback){
    let i = new Image();
    i.src = `chrome-extension://${extId}/${iconFile}`;
    i.onload = ()=>{callback(true)};
    i.onerror = ()=>{callback(false)};
}
```

Но это не сработало. Есть ли рабочий способ сделать это?

Answer (score 0):

Универсального способа, насколько мне известно, нет. Нужно заранее исследовать интересующие расширения и проверить, в манифесте, какие файлы доступны в `web_accessible_resources`. Ниже пример для расширения [AdBlock](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adblock-%E2%80%94-best-ad-blocker/gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom?hl=ru):

```js
function detect() {
  let i = new Image();
  i.onload = () => console.log('установлено');
  i.onerror = () => console.log('не установлено или отключено');
  i.src = 'chrome-extension://gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom/adblock-ads-blocked-icon.svg';
}
```

```html
<button onclick=detect()>Проверить</button>
```

Comment: А если в web_accessible_resources ничего нет? Например, у Tampermonkey web_accessible_resources пуст, а мне надо отслеживать именно его, т.к. без него юзерскрипты не работают

Comment: @Nikita, а более детально проблему можно описать? На сайте есть какой-то скрипт, которому требуется юзерскрипт Tampermonkey?

Comment: у меня сайт с юзерскриптами, нужно пользователям предлагать установку Tampermonkey, если он не установлен